# Pandas: Get time delta for each block of datetimes in same column

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have the below dataframe where I am wanting total the time of the ID number. I cant just do *.max() - .min()*, need to add each block then sum, e.g. from 06:00:01 to 06:00:32 is 31 secs, 19:53:29 to 19:54:52 is 1:23 and 01:58:00 to 1:58:50 is 50 secs, total 164 secs.

```
ID No.  TimeStamp
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:01
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:02
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:04
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:06
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:09
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:12
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:14
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:17
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:26
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:28
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:30
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:32
18507   19/04/2023 19:53:29
18507   19/04/2023 19:53:39
18507   19/04/2023 19:53:41
18507   19/04/2023 19:53:48
18507   19/04/2023 19:53:55
18507   19/04/2023 19:53:56
18507   19/04/2023 19:54:04
18507   19/04/2023 19:54:06
18507   19/04/2023 19:54:52
18507   20/04/2023 1:58:00
18507   20/04/2023 1:58:05
18507   20/04/2023 1:58:05
18507   20/04/2023 1:58:05
18507   20/04/2023 1:58:09
18507   20/04/2023 1:58:36
18507   20/04/2023 1:58:38
18507   20/04/2023 1:58:46
18507   20/04/2023 1:58:50
```

My idea was to make a decision boundary with *df['diff'] = (df['TimeStamp'] - df['TimeStamp'].shift(1))* and then *df['diff_truth'] = df['diff'] < '01:00:00'*

```
............
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:28  0 days 00:00:06  True
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:30  0 days 00:00:06  True
18507   19/04/2023 6:00:32  0 days 00:00:08  True
18507   19/04/2023 19:53:29 0 days 13:48:27  False
18507   19/04/2023 19:53:39 0 days 00:00:10  True
18507   19/04/2023 19:53:41 0 days 00:00:02  True
```

With this, get timedelta from *19/04/2023 6:00:01 to 19/04/2023 6:00:32* and so on.

What would be the next step after this, so can use *.max() - .min()* to get the time difference up to the False for each block, then sum each block of time i guess to get the total for the ID. Or is there a better way?

**UPDATE**

1.Solved but creating a decision boundary. False for more than 1hr between timestamps.

```
def make_tof(df):
    df.TimeStamp = pd.to_datetime(df.TimeStamp)
    df.sort_values(by=['ID No.', 'TimeStamp'], inplace=True)
    df['diff'] = (df['TimeStamp'] - df['TimeStamp'].shift(1))
    # assumption: more than 1 hr
    df['diff_day'] = df['diff'].astype(str).str[:2]
    df['diff_truth1'] = df['diff'] < '01:00:00'
    df = df[df['diff_day'] != '-1']
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return df
```

2.create a new df for each ID, make a df of dics, then do groupbys.

```
def cal_time(df):
    new_df = []

    df = make_tof(df)  # make decision boundary
    #  make df per ID
    lst_ID = df['ID No.'].unique()

    for j in lst_RID:
        df_ID = df[df['ID No.'] == j]
        d = {x: y for x, y in df_ID.loc[df_ID['diff_truth1'].ne(0)].groupby(df_ID['diff_truth1'].eq(0).cumsum())}

        for i in d:
            df3 = d[i].groupby(['ID No.'])['diff'].agg('sum')
            new_df.append(df3)
     
    a = pd.concat(new_df)
    a = pd.DataFrame(a)
    a = a.groupby(['ID No.'])['diff'].agg('sum')
```

Not elegant but get the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID No.": [
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
            18507,
        ],
        "TimeStamp": [
            "19/04/2023 6:00:01",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:02",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:04",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:06",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:09",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:12",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:14",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:17",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:26",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:28",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:30",
            "19/04/2023 6:00:32",
            "19/04/2023 19:53:29",
            "19/04/2023 19:53:39",
            "19/04/2023 19:53:41",
            "19/04/2023 19:53:48",
            "19/04/2023 19:53:55",
            "19/04/2023 19:53:56",
            "19/04/2023 19:54:04",
            "19/04/2023 19:54:06",
            "19/04/2023 19:54:52",
            "20/04/2023 1:58:00",
            "20/04/2023 1:58:05",
            "20/04/2023 1:58:05",
            "20/04/2023 1:58:05",
            "20/04/2023 1:58:09",
            "20/04/2023 1:58:36",
            "20/04/2023 1:58:38",
            "20/04/2023 1:58:46",
            "20/04/2023 1:58:50",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df["TimeStamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TimeStamp"], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df["year"] = df["TimeStamp"].dt.year
df["month"] = df["TimeStamp"].dt.month
df["day"] = df["TimeStamp"].dt.day
df["hour"] = df["TimeStamp"].dt.hour

new_df = (
    df.groupby(
        [
            "ID No.",
            "year",
            "month",
            "day",
            "hour",
        ]
    )
    .agg(list)["TimeStamp"]
    .apply(
        lambda x: sum(
            [(max(x) - min(x)).total_seconds() for i in range(len(x)) if i + 1 < len(x)]
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
    .groupby(["ID No."])
    .agg({"TimeStamp": sum})
    .rename(columns={"TimeStamp": "Total seconds"})
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output

   ID No.  Total seconds
0   18507           1405
```